# How can I convert a UTC timestamp to local time, seconds past the hour?

Tags: c++, utc

I have a large data set with timestamps that are in UTC time in milliseconds. I'm synchronizing this data set with another's who has timestamps of microseconds *past the hour*, so I need to convert the first to local time, in seconds past the hour.

Most of the similar questions I've read on this subject get UTC time from the time() function which gets the current time.

I've tried implementing the following which was pulled from [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/gmtime/).

The timestamp I'm trying to convert is a double, but I'm not sure how to actually use this value.

An example ts from my data set: 1512695257869

```
int main ()
{
  double my_utc_ts; //value acquired from the data set

  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * ptm;

  time ( &rawtime ); //getting current time
  //rawtime = my_utc_ts;  //this is what I tried and is wrong, and results in a nullptr

  ptm = gmtime ( &rawtime );

  puts ("Current time around the World:");
  printf ("Phoenix, AZ (U.S.) :  %2d:%02d\n", (ptm->tm_hour+MST)%24, ptm->tm_min);

  return 0;
}
```

After I'm able to convert it to a usable gmtime object or whatever, I need to get seconds past the hour... I think I'll be able to figure this part out if I can get the UTC timestamps to successfully convert, but I haven't thought this far ahead.

Guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After I'm able to convert it to a usable gmtime object or whatever, I need to get seconds past the hour...

Here is how you can convert a double representing milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC to seconds past the local hour using [Howard Hinnant's, free, open-source, C++11/14/17 timezone library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html) which is based on `<chrono>`:

```
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace date;
    double my_utc_ts = 1512695257869;
    using ms = duration<double, std::milli>;
    sys_time<milliseconds> utc_ms{round<milliseconds>(ms{my_utc_ts})};
    auto loc_s = make_zoned(current_zone(), floor<seconds>(utc_ms)).get_local_time();
    auto sec_past_hour = loc_s - floor<hours>(loc_s);
    std::cout << utc_ms << " UTC\n";
    std::cout << sec_past_hour << " past the local hour\n";
}
```

This outputs for me:

```
2017-12-08 01:07:37.869 UTC
457s past the local hour
```

If your local time zone is not an integral number of hours offset from UTC, the second line of output will be different for you.

### Explanation of code:

We start with your input `my_utc_ts`.

The next line creates a custom `std::chrono::duration` that has `double` as the representation and `milliseconds` as the precision.  This type-alias is named `ms`.

The next line constructs `utc_ms` which is a `std::chrono::time_point<system_clock, milliseconds>` holding 1512695257869, and represents the time point 2017-12-08 01:07:37.869 UTC.  So far, no actual computation has been performed.  Simply the `double 1512695257869` has been cast into a type which represents an integral number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

This line starts the computation:

```
auto loc_s = make_zoned(current_zone(), floor<seconds>(utc_ms)).get_local_time();
```

This creates a `{time_zone, system_time}` pair capable of mapping between UTC and a local time, using `time_zone` as that map.  It uses `current_zone()` to find the computer's current time zone, and truncates the time point `utc_ms` from a precision of milliseconds to a precision of seconds.  Finally the trailing `.get_local_time()` extracts the local time from this mapping, with a precision of seconds, and mapped into the current time zone.  That is, `loc_s` is a count of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, offset by your-local-time-zone's UTC offset that was in effect at 2017-12-08 01:07:37 UTC.

Now if you truncate `loc_s` to a precision of hours, and subtract that truncated time point from `loc_s`, you'll get the seconds past the local hour:

```
auto sec_past_hour = loc_s - floor<hours>(loc_s);
```

The entire computation is just the two lines of code above.  The next two lines simply stream out `utc_ms` and `sec_past_hour`.

Assuming that your local time zone was offset from UTC by an integral number of hours at 2017-12-08 01:07:37 UTC, you can double-check that:

```
457 == 7*60 + 37
```

Indeed, *if* you can *assume* that your local time zone is always offset from UTC by an integral number of hours, the above program can be simplified by not mapping into local time at all:

```
sys_time<milliseconds> utc_ms{round<milliseconds>(ms{my_utc_ts})};
auto utc_s = floor<seconds>(utc_ms);
auto sec_past_hour = utc_s - floor<hours>(utc_s);
```

The results will be identical.

(*Warning:* Not all time zones are offset from UTC by an integral number of hours)

And if your database is known to be generated with a time zone that is not the computer's current local time zone, that can be taken into account by replacing `current_zone()` with the IANA time zone identifier that your database was generated with, for example:

```
auto loc_s = make_zoned("America/New_York", floor<seconds>(utc_ms)).get_local_time();
```

### Update

This entire library is based on the std `<chrono>` library introduced with C++11.  The types above `utc_ms` and `loc_s` are instantiations of `std::chrono::time_point`, and `sec_past_hour` has type `std::chrono::seconds` (which is itself an instantiation of `std::chrono::duration`).

`duration`s can be converted to their "representation" type using the `.count()` member function.  For `seconds`, this representation type will be a signed 64 bit integer.

For a more detailed video tutorial on `<chrono>`, please see this [Cppcon 2016 presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M).  This presentation will encourage you to avoid using the `.count()` member function as much as humanly possible.

For example instead of converting `sec_past_hour` to a `long` so that you can compare it to other values of your dataset, convert other values of your dataset to `std::chrono::duration`s so that you can compare them to `sec_past_hour`.

For example:

```
long other_data = 123456789;  // past the hour in microseconds
if (microseconds{other_data} < sec_past_hour)
    // ...
```

This snippet shows how `<chrono>` will take care of units conversions for you.  This means you won't make mistakes like dividing by 1,000,000 when you should have multiplied, or spelling "million" with the wrong number of zeroes.

Comment: Can I convert sec_past_hour back to a primitive data type? This way it can I can compare it to the values of the other data set.

This was amazing help. Thanks so much.

Comment: Yes, that can be done.  But see the updated answer on that point.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by converting the floating point number to a `time_t`. A `time_t` is normally a count of seconds since an epoch (most often the POSIX epoch--midnight, 1 Jan 1970), so it sounds like that's going to take little more than a bit of fairly simple math.

So let's assume for the sake of argument that your input uses a different epoch. Just for the sake of argument let's assume it's using an epoch of midnight, 1 jan 1900 instead (and, as noted, it's in milliseconds instead of seconds).

So, to convert that to a `time_t`, you'd start by dividing by 1000 to convert from milliseconds to seconds. Then you'd subtract off the number of seconds between midnight 1 jan 1900 and midnight 1 jan 1970. Now you have a value you can treat as a `time_t` that the standard library can deal with<sup>1</sup>.

Then use `localtime` to get that same time as a `struct tm`.

Then zero out the minutes and seconds from that `tm`, and use `mktime` to get a `time_t` representing that time.

Finally, use `difftime` to get the difference between the two.

---

<sup>1. For the moment, I'm assuming your standard library is based around a standard POSIX epoch, but that's a pretty safe assumption.</sup>